# Trying to get button to activate a function that will print text

Tags: javascript

I am making a text based adventure game. Right now I only have the gender selection. After selecting the gender, you are prompted with a screen that will have a string and a button. What I am trying to do, is start the game (simply print a string of the first scenario) once the button is clicked.

This is the code I have so far...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><title>Adventure Game</title>
<link src="/home/logan/game2" type="text/javascript">
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

confirm("Ready to play?");
    var age = prompt("How old are you?");
    if (age >= 18) {
        document.write(" "); 
    } else {
         document.write("You're less than 18? You better just stay         home, filthy pansy.");
    }
    document.write("Please select your gender.")
 </script>
 <p>
 <select id="genderlist"> 
     <option value="null"> </option>
     <option value='Male'> Male </option>
     <option value='Female'> Female </option>
     <option value='Other'> Other </option>
  </select>
 </p>
 <script>
 document.getElementById("genderlist").onchange = function() {
    var gender=document.getElementById("genderlist").value;

    if(gender=="Male"){
    document.write("Okay");
    document.write('<p><button id="start" onclick="function()"> Lets begin, shall we?</button></p>');
    }
    else if(gender=="Female"){
    document.write("Sounds Good");
    document.write('<p><button id="start"> Lets begin, shall we?</button></p>');
    }
    else{
    document.write("I don't think this will be for you.");
    }
    return false
 };
 </script>
 <script>
 document.getElementById("start").onclick = function(){
     document.write("<p> This is nice </p>");

 };



 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Is there some obvious mistake that I am overlooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Your issue

The problem is that you set the button `click` listener *too earlier*. I mean that your `<button>` doesn't exist and has not been inserted in the DOM.
So `document.getElementById("start")` is `null` when you initialize it.

#### My solution

- [more cleaner] I used [`.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) instead of `document.write`.
- [fun] I put the confirm in a `if` statement. If the visitor is not ready, he doesn't to play ;)
- [your issue] I set the button `click` listener **after** the button has been [created and append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) in the body.

```js
if (confirm("Ready to play?")) {
    var age = prompt("How old are you?");
    if (age < 18) {
         document.body.appendChild( createElement("p", "You're less than 18? You better just stay home, filthy pansy.") );
    }
    document.body.appendChild( createElement("p", "Please select your gender."));
 
 document.getElementById("genderlist").onchange = function() {
    var gender=document.getElementById("genderlist").value;

    if(gender==="Male"){
      document.body.appendChild( createElement("p", "Okay") );
      var button = createElement("button", "Lets begin, shall we?", "start");
      document.body.appendChild( button );
      // Set listener
      document.getElementById("start").onclick = function(){
        document.body.appendChild( createElement("p", "This is nice") );
      };
    }
    else if(gender==="Female"){
      document.body.appendChild( createElement("p", "Sounds Good") );
      var button = createElement("button", "Lets begin, shall we?", "start");
      document.body.appendChild( button );
      // Set listener
      document.getElementById("start").onclick = function(){
        document.body.appendChild( createElement("p", "This is nice") );
      };
    }
    else{
      document.body.appendChild( createElement("p", "I don't think this will be for you.") );
    }
    return false
 };
}
function createElement(type, text, id){
  var el = document.createElement(type);
  if (id) {
    el.id = id;
  }
  el.innerHTML = text;
  return el;
}
```

```html
<p>
 <select id="genderlist"> 
     <option value="null"> </option>
     <option value='Male'> Male </option>
     <option value='Female'> Female </option>
     <option value='Other'> Other </option>
  </select>
 </p>
```

The `createElement()` function is here just because I don't like duplicate code and I'm lazy.